# how to fix this error void android.webkit.WebView.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null

Tags: android, html

Background webview is given. When running it gives error how to fix this error.        recipe_description = findViewById(R.id.recipe_description);  recipe_description this web view id No data coming in webview How to fix this error String htmlText = "file:///android_asset/aboutcertified.html"; this data html not load why

```
public class ActivityRecipeDaily extends AppCompatActivity {
private WebView recipe_description;
SharedPref sharedPref;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Tools.getTheme(this);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_detail2);
    Tools.getLayoutDirections(this, RTL_MODE);
    recipe_description.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    recipe_description.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    recipe_description.setFocusable(false);
    recipe_description.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");

    recipe_description = findViewById(R.id.recipe_description);

    WebSettings webSettings = recipe_description.getSettings();
    Resources res = getResources();
    int fontSize = res.getInteger(R.integer.font_size);
    webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(fontSize);

    String mimeType = "text/html; charset=UTF-8";
    String encoding = "utf-8";
    String htmlText = "file:///android_asset/aboutcertified.html";
    String bg_paragraph;
    if (sharedPref.getIsDarkTheme()) {
        bg_paragraph = "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #eeeeee;}";
    } else {
        bg_paragraph = "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #000000;}";
    }

    String font_style_default = "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/font/custom_font.ttf\")}body {font-family: MyFont; font-size: medium; text-align: left;}</style>";

    String text = "<html><head>"
            + font_style_default
            + "<style>img{max-width:100%;height:auto;} figure{max-width:100%;height:auto;} iframe{width:100%;}</style> "
            + bg_paragraph
            + "</style></head>"
            + "<body>"
            + htmlText
            + "</body></html>";

    String text_rtl = "<html dir='rtl'><head>"
            + font_style_default
            + "<style>img{max-width:100%;height:auto;} figure{max-width:100%;height:auto;} iframe{width:100%;}</style> "
            + bg_paragraph
            + "</style></head>"
            + "<body>"
            + htmlText
            + "</body></html>";

    if (RTL_MODE) {
        recipe_description.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text_rtl, mimeType, encoding, null);
    } else {
        recipe_description.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, mimeType, encoding, null);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello [@jayraman jay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20801452/jayaraman-jay), I have added comment to fix your error. Check it out

```
    public class ActivityRecipeDaily extends AppCompatActivity {
    private WebView recipe_description;
    SharedPref sharedPref;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Tools.getTheme(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipe_detail2);
        Tools.getLayoutDirections(this, RTL_MODE);

        recipe_description = findViewById(R.id.recipe_description); // You need to initialize your webview before accessing its methods otherwise it will give you NullPointerException.
        recipe_description.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        recipe_description.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
        recipe_description.setFocusable(false);
        recipe_description.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");

        WebSettings webSettings = recipe_description.getSettings();
        Resources res = getResources();
        int fontSize = res.getInteger(R.integer.font_size);
        webSettings.setDefaultFontSize(fontSize);

        String mimeType = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";
        String htmlText = "file:///android_asset/aboutcertified.html";
        String bg_paragraph;
        if (sharedPref.getIsDarkTheme()) {
            bg_paragraph = "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #eeeeee;}";
        } else {
            bg_paragraph = "<style type=\"text/css\">body{color: #000000;}";
        }

        String font_style_default = "<style type=\"text/css\">@font-face {font-family: MyFont;src: url(\"file:///android_asset/font/custom_font.ttf\")}body {font-family: MyFont; font-size: medium; text-align: left;}</style>";

        String text = "<html><head>" +
            font_style_default +
            "<style>img{max-width:100%;height:auto;} figure{max-width:100%;height:auto;} iframe{width:100%;}</style> " +
            bg_paragraph +
            "</style></head>" +
            "<body>" +
            htmlText +
            "</body></html>";

        String text_rtl = "<html dir='rtl'><head>" +
            font_style_default +
            "<style>img{max-width:100%;height:auto;} figure{max-width:100%;height:auto;} iframe{width:100%;}</style> " +
            bg_paragraph +
            "</style></head>" +
            "<body>" +
            htmlText +
            "</body></html>";
       
        // Update this condition into your code.

        if (RTL_MODE) {
            recipe_description.loadData(text_rtl, mimeType , encoding);
        } else {
            recipe_description.loadData(text, mimeType , encoding);
        }

    }
```

You were using

> webview.loadDataWithBaseURL(null, text, mimeType, encoding, null)

method of webview and passing **null** at the place of required **baseUrl** parameter of that method so it will load nothing into the webview.

Hope you will get solution after this. Let me know if you have any other issues.

Happy coding!!

Comment: application crash error 'java.lang.Boolean com.Tamiltv.newspaper.databases.prefs.SharedPref.getIsDarkTheme()' on a null object reference

Comment: You need to initialize your sharedPref instance below( **Tools.getLayoutDirections(this, RTL_MODE); **)  line.